# Buttons and links in the area of the folded out menu are not clickable

Tags: javascript, html, css, menu

I've got an issue with the menu for my webpage. 
The menu is working pretty fine, but all the buttons or links that appear in the area of the folded-out menu are not clickable.

[image]

Anybody got a clue what's wrong with my code? You can find it below and on codepen.io

[menu on codepen.io](https://codepen.io/chrizzy/pen/XxxQGK)

**Code (HTML, CSS, JS):**

```js
toggle = document.querySelectorAll(".toggle")[0];
nav = document.querySelectorAll("nav")[0];
toggle_open_text = 'Menu';
toggle_close_text = 'Close';

toggle.addEventListener('click', function() {
 nav.classList.toggle('open');
 
  if (nav.classList.contains('open')) {
    toggle.innerHTML = toggle_close_text;
  } else {
    toggle.innerHTML = toggle_open_text;
  }
}, false);

setTimeout(function(){
 nav.classList.toggle('open'); 
}, 800);
```

```css
$size : 40px;
$items : 7;
$transition : .5s;
$bounce : cubic-bezier(.3,1.4,.5,.9);
$color-inner : #343b4c;
$color-outer : #3f5f94;
$background: mix($color-inner, $color-outer);
$black : shade($color-outer, 80%);
$start-scale : .5;
$start-rot : 190deg;

nav {
 z-index: 10;
 display: block;
 position: fixed;
 width: $size * $items * 2;
 height: $size * $items * 2;
 user-select: none;
 transform: translate3d($size*.5,-$size*.5,0);
 transition: transform $transition $bounce;
 color:white !important;
 
 &.open {
  transform: translate3d(0,0,0);
 }
 
 &.top-right {
  top: -$size * ($items - 2.2);
  right: -$size * ($items - 2.2);
 }
}

nav a{ 
 position: absolute;
 display: inline-block;
 text-align: center;
 cursor: pointer;
 font: $size*.5 Lato, sans-serif;
 line-height: $size * .8;
 padding-top: $size * .2;
 border-radius: $size * $items;
 transform: scale3d($start-scale, $start-scale, $start-scale) rotate3d(0,0,1,$start-rot);
 pointer-events: none;
 opacity: 0;
 cursor: pointer;
 transition: transform $transition $bounce, opacity $transition;
 color: white !important;
 div {
  transform: rotate(180deg);
 }
}
nav.open a {
 pointer-events: auto;
 opacity: 1; 
}

@for $i from 1 through $items {
 nav a:nth-child(#{$i}){
  $i : $i - 1;
  $-i : $items - $i;
  $pct : ($i+1)/$items * 100%;
  $color :  mix($color-inner, $color-outer, $pct);
  
  top: $i * $size;
  left: $i * $size;
  right: $i * $size;
  bottom: $i * $size;
  background: $color;
  transition-delay: $i * $transition/$items;
 }
}

@for $i from 1 through $items {
 a:nth-child(#{$i}){
  $i : $i - 1;
  $-i : $items - $i;
  $pct : ($i+1)/$items * 100%;
  $color :  mix($color-inner, $color-outer, $pct);

  nav.open & {
   transition-delay: $i * $transition/$items;
   transform: scale3d(1,1,1) rotate3d(0,0,1,$start-rot);
   opacity: 1;
   
   &:hover {
    background: #343b4c;
    color: white !important;
    text-decoration:none;
    transition-delay: 0s;
   }
 
   &:active {
    background: shade($color, 50%);
    color: white !important;
    text-decoration:none;
   }
   
   &.toggle {
    transform: scale3d(.9,.9,.9) rotate3d(0,0,1,$start-rot - 180deg);
   }
  }
 }
}


.toggle {
 line-height: $size*2;
 padding: 0;
 width: $size*2;
 background: $color-inner;
 opacity: 1;
 transform: none;
 pointer-events: auto;
 transition-delay: 0s;
 
 .open & {
  transform: rotate3d(0,0,1,0deg);
 }

 &:hover {
  background: shade($color-inner, 90%);
  color: $color-inner;
 }
 &:active {
  background: shade($color-inner, 50%);
  color: rgba($color-inner, .5);
  transform: scale(.9);
  transition-duration: 0s;
 }
}
```

```html
<nav class="top-right open">
 <a class="disc l1">
  <div>Messages</div>
 </a>
 <a class="disc l2">
  <div>Photos</div>
 </a>
 <a class="disc l3">
  <div>Profile</div>
 </a>
 <a class="disc l4">
  <div>Likes</div>
 </a>
 <a class="disc l5">
  <div>Likes</div>
 </a>
 <a class="disc l6">
  <div>Likes</div>
 </a>
 <a class="disc l7 toggle">
  Menu
 </a>
</nav>
```

Comment: Add a background color to your nav element, then you see what the problem is …

Comment: When you're asking about HTML and CSS, please provide what the browser sees, not your back-end templating and uncompiled SCSS.

Answer (score 5):

You need to add a `href` attributes to your anchors, like this:

```
<a href="https://stackoverflow.com" class="disc l1">
    <div>Messages</div>
</a>
```

Whole html:

```
<nav class="top-right open">
    <a href="test1" class="disc l1">
        <div>Messages</div>
    </a>
    <a href="test2" class="disc l2">
        <div>Photos</div>
    </a>
    <a href="test3" class="disc l3">
        <div>Profile</div>
    </a>
    <a href="test4" class="disc l4">
        <div>Likes</div>
    </a>
    <a href="test5" class="disc l5">
        <div>Likes</div>
    </a>
    <a href="test6" class="disc l6">
        <div>Likes</div>
    </a>
    <a href="close" class="disc l7 toggle">
        Menu
    </a>
</nav>
```

Comment: @ChristineHümmer I dont really understand your problem, if you provide some more information I can take a look at it. In the codepen you linked it looks fine.

Comment: Thanks for your hint. I already put anchors in the menu for using it on the webpage. The menu works pretty fine, but I still have the issue with the "background" when the menu is folded-in. When there is a button / link in the area of the folded-out menu it is not clickable unfortunately. I think that's because of the opacity. But I do not know how to solve this issue as I am not a HTML/CSS expert. :-(